# Error resizing picklist and panel. Panel overlaps position of picklist

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have in one line a pickList and a panel but when I resize window then the panel overlaps pickList. Please see below code and screen(https://gofile.io/?c=iAqMJh). Only when panel arrives the arrows of the pickList then resizing happens without any error.

```
                                        <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
                                            <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2">
                                                <p:outputLabel
                                                                value="#{pageMsgs['citiesMSG.aaaa']}"
                                                                style="font-weight: bold" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="ui-md-4 ui-g-12">
                                                <h:panelGroup>
                                                    <p:pickList id="pick1"
                                                        value="#{citiesBean.rowLevelCities}"
                                                        converter="#{pickListConverter}" var="cities"
                                                        responisve="true"
                                                        itemLabel="#{cities.name}" itemValue="#{cities}"
                                                        disabled="#{!citiesController.isEditMode(true)}">

                                                        <p:ajax event="transfer"
                                                            listener="#{citiesController.onTransferCityHeader}"
                                                            update="pick1 panelH" />

                                                    </p:pickList>
                                                </h:panelGroup>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="ui-md-6 ui-g-12">
                                                <p:panel header="Header"
                                                    id="panelH">
                                                    <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
                                                        <div class="ui-md-3 ui-g-12">
                                                            <p:outputLabel
                                                                value="#{pageMsgs['citiesMSG.cityHeader']}"
                                                                style="font-weight: bold" />
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="ui-md-1 ui-g-12" />
                                                        <div class="ui-md-3 ui-g-12">
                                                            <p:outputLabel
                                                                value="#{pageMsgs['citiesMSG.cityHeader']}"
                                                                style="font-weight: bold" />
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </p:panel>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

I'm using JSF 2.2

Comment: You can increase chances of getting help by editing your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: And you don't resize the panel and picklist, you resize the window with a panel and picklist in a responsive grid... So if you put two fixed width div's in place of the panel and picklist you don't have the problem?

Comment: If I use other primefaces components then I do not have any problem. I believe that pickList causes the problem.